# Show only selected figures of generated figures in a cache in knitr

Tags: r, knitr

If I have a chunk that generates 4 figures and I want to keep them all (fig.keep=all), is it possible to show only the second one using a cache option?  I see that echo=2:5 can be selected, but it doesn't seem that fig.show=2 is possible.  Is the best method to do \includegraphcis{fig2.pdf}?

Thanks.

Comment: I don't recommend doing `\includegraphcis{fig2.pdf}` as you never know if the figure name won't change in the future...

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to keep all figures you can simply use :
Use argument `fig.keep=c(2,4)`

Reproducible example :

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\begin{document}
<<load_libraries, echo = FALSE, eval = TRUE, results ="hide">>=
library(knitr) 
@

<<multiplefig, fig.keep=c(2,4),fig.height=4,fig.with=10, out.width='.8\\linewidth'>>=
mapply(function(X)plot(X,main=X),c(1:4))
@

\end{document}
```

[image]

---

However, since you want to keep figures, I would do it the old way in sweave, save the figures using `png` or `pdf`.

Reproducible example :

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{graphicx} 
\graphicspath{{figure/}}
\begin{document}


<<multiplefig,  echo=FALSE>>=
for (i in 1:4){
  png(file=paste0(getwd(),"/figure/fig",i,".png"))
  plot(1,1,main=i,cex.main=4)
  dev.off()
}
@
This plot shows only figure \ref{fig:fig2} but 4 other are saved
\begin{figure}[htbp]
\centering
\includegraphics[width=0.5\textwidth]{fig2.png}
\caption{}
\label{fig:fig2}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]